# django blocktrans external url

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am building a web app using django framework. At one of my template, I'd like to put a hyperlink to **external URL**.

At this template, I need to have two languages, so I decided to use django blocktrans tag. From [the django  documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag)), I could only put **internal URL** as the URL. CMIIW.

How do I put my external URL?

eg. this is the template.html for english language. I put http://external/docs/en/ as the hyperlink

```
{% blocktrans %}
Hello, how are you? <a href="http://external/docs/en/" target="new">Lorem ipsum</a>. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

while for german language, I need to put http://external/docs/de/ as the hyperlink

```
{% blocktrans %}
Hello, how are you? <a href="http://external/docs/de/" target="new">Lorem ipsum</a>. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

While the example at the django docs is only for internal URL.

```
{% if LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' %}
  {% url 'views.doc.en' as urldoc %}
{% else %}
  {% url 'views.doc.de' as urldoc %}
{% endif %}
{% blocktrans %}
Hello, how are you? <a href={{ urldoc }} target="new">Lorem ipsum</a>. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the language code with `{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}` in the template and add it to the url. For example:

```
{% blocktrans %}
Hello, how are you? <a href=http://external/docs/{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}/ target="new">Lorem ipsum</a>. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

When the user has English language selected `{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}` will be `en`. If the user has German language selected `{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}` will be `de`

Therefore, the links will be:

- For English: http://external/docs/en/
- For German: http://external/docs/de/

Comment: but, with that snippet, how do I put the if/else statement? So far, my idea is create views for each external link and put the if/else statement before the blocktrans tag.

Comment: With this snippet you don't need the is/else statement because the url with the correct language code is built dynamically with {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}

Answer (score 0):

So far, my solution is create function at `views.py` which will redirect to external URL.

```
@login_required
def doc_en():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://external/docs/en')

@login_required
def doc_de():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://external/docs/de')
```